# How to map unknown columns using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a database that from time to time gets or has columns removed. Is it possible to map these columns using Hibernate if the column names and data types are not known beforehand? Something like:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_table")
public class SomeTable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.Entity)
    private String id;

    // private List<Object> fields;
}
```

Comment: And what would you do with these unmapped columns?

Comment: Return them to the client that called the API

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible through entities because Hibernate selects exactly the columns you mapped instead of doing a `select *`. You can run a native query and run `select *` though.